# Show/hide multiple Divs with links

Tags: javascript, html, css

I didn't clearly explain what I was trying to do. Hopefully this will be better.

Currently I'm using [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bk7g0uL/2/) to toggle some divs. It acts as an accordion and shows only one div at a time. Clicking one of the titles will show the content of that div and clicking another title will hide the first div and show that one.

What I am having trouble with (and would like to do) is when opening one div I would like to hide access to the other divs until that first div is closed.

Meaning if I Click on "Content2" to show that content, I would like to hide access to Content1, Content3, and Content4 until Content 2 is closed again.

```js
function ReverseDisplay(d) {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle.active:not(#' + d + ')');
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  document.getElementById(d).classList.toggle('active')

}
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: none;
}
.toggle.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('content1')">
 Content1
</a>
<a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('content2')">
 Content2
</a>
<a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('content3')">
 Content3
</a>
<a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('content4')">
 Content4
</a>

<div id="content1" class="toggle">
  <p>Content 1 goes here.</p>
</div>
<div id="content2" class="toggle">
  <p>Content 2 goes here.</p>
</div>
<div id="content3" class="toggle">
  <p>Content 3 goes here.</p>
</div>
<div id="content4" class="toggle">
  <p>Content 4 goes here.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: then how will goint to open that link again?

Comment: Your question is if this is possible? Yes, it's certainly possible.

Comment: Yes, very possible. If you make some attempt(s) of your own and have problems feel free to return, display your attempt(s) and I'm sure someone will debug it and explain the issue maybe offer a solution.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Answer (score 2):

This should work... Use the `id` passed to identify the element and add class by checking if `active` exists.

```js
function ReverseDisplay(d) {
  var id = d
  var el = document.getElementById(id)
  var elClassList = el.classList
  var [...active] = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle.active')
  debugger
  if (active.length === 0) {
    el.classList.add('active')
  } else if (id === active[0].id) {
    el.classList.remove('active')
  }
}
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.toggle.active {
  display: block;
}
a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('uniquename')">
    Click to show/hide.
</a>
<div id="uniquename" class="toggle">
  <p>Content 1 goes here.</p>
</div>

<a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('uniquename1')" style="left:150px">
    Click to show/hide.
</a>
<div id="uniquename1" class="toggle">
  <p>Content 2 goes here.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think he is asking for an accordion function style, when clicking one link show its div and hide all others. I am going to edit your answer with the proper code for that purpose.

Comment: @Dez That is not a requirement. Don't speculate your own requirement.

Comment: *"Meaning, if I click on 'uniquename' to show its content can I hide the link to 'uniquename1' while it's open?"* Not an speculation out of hand.

Comment: @Dez is correct, I was trying for an accordion style. My apologies if I did not explain it properly.

Comment: @Pranesh, I don't think I clearly explained what I was trying to do. I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: @PraneshRavi, your code appears to do the same as mine. It toggles the divs but if I open one I can still click on the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript function in order to achieve *accordion style* behaviour, for as many links as you might want to have.

```
function ReverseDisplay(d) {
  var els = document.getElementById(d);
  if (els.classList.contains('active')){
    els.classList.remove('active');
  }else{
    var activeDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
    for (var i = 0; i < activeDivs.length; i++) {
        activeDivs[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
    els.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

Comment: Dez, this script does toggle the content (div) by clicking on the link. Is it also possible to hide the remaining links while one is active?

Comment: It is possible, but it would be useful? If you hide the remaining links when one is active how do you plan to access later to the content in them?

Comment: By closing the open div. Since it acts as an accordion the idea was to close the div to see the remaining links.

Comment: Update your question with an example of what you need.

Comment: I thought that is what I was asking for but didn't clearly explain. I updated the question, hopefully this will be better.